# A PHP Regex for list Items and line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I need a Regex to search for *"item one"* and get *"Amet Elit"*. Or *"Title"* and get *"One sentence with\na linebreak!"*

```
- item one: Amet Elit
- Title: One sentence with 
a line break!
- Desc: Hello and thank you for your help!
```

So the Regex has to find everything after `-`, some specific words and a `:`. And this string ends before a line break with a following `-`.

I tried this

```
/[^-\s'item one']:*(.*)/g
```

under https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
/^- ([^:]*): (.*(?>\R.*)*?(?=\R- |\R*\z))/m
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM0kH0/1)

The *key* and the *value* are captured in group 1 and group 2. The group 2 contains a non-greedy quantifier to match until the condition in the lookahead succeeds. The lookahead `(?=...)` checks if the second group is followed by a newline (`\R`) or the end of the string (`\z`)

To obtain a specific item, replace `([^:]*)` with whatever you want.

Comment: Wow, great! This answer works for me! Thank you all :)

Comment: @JonasZielke: note that if you plan to query your string several times, it may be better to grab all key/values of the string once and for all with `preg_match_all` and to build an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this search function:

```
function srch($input, $key) {
    preg_match('/(?<=\b' . preg_quote($key, '/') . ': ).*?(?=\n-|$)/s', $input, $m);
    return $m[0];
}
```

Then call it as:

```
$input = "- item one: Amet Elit
- Title: One sentence with
a line break!
- Desc: Hello and thank you for your help!";

php> echo srch($input, 'Title')
One sentence with
a line break!

php> echo srch($input, 'item one')
Amet Elit

php> echo srch($input, 'Desc')
Hello and thank you for your help!
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/497268)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
^-\h*([^:\R]*)\h*:\h*(.*$(?:\R[^-].*$)*)
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/xO4mX1/1).

Broken up in parts:

- `^-\h*([^:\R]*)\h*`: matches the words between the starting hyphen (must occur at line start) up to a colon, trimmed (`\h*` are horizontal blanks outside the capture). There cannot be line-breaks in that part (`\R`)
- `\h*(.*)`: matches the rest of the line (left-trimmed).
- `(?:\R[^-].*$)*`: non-capturing (`(?:`) group allowing zero or more lines following, on the condition they do not start with a hyphen (`\R[^-]`).

In PHP:

```
$input = "- item one: Amet Elit
- Title: One sentence with 
a line break!
- Desc: Hello and thank you for your help!";

preg_match_all("#^-\s*([^:\R]*)\s*:\s*(.*(?:\R[^-].*$)*)#m",
               $input, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $prefix) {
    echo $prefix . " | " . $matches[2][$i] . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

> item one | Amet Elit
>
> Title | One sentence with
>
> a line break!
>
> Desc | Hello and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^- item one: ).*$
```

If the phrase (`item one` in the above example) is not constant, you could use `\K` to drop everything matched so far to achieve a positive lookbehind with variable length:

```
^- [^:]*: \K.*$
```

---

Here is a slight alternation to allow you to match over multiple lines. Don't forget the `gm` flags

```
^- [^:]*: \K(.|\n)*?(?=^-|$)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/uU7wM7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off.

Instead of matching exactly with `item one` you want to match with a word or space, so that would be `[\w\s]*`

Something along the lines of `^- [\w\s]*: (.*)` should work, though you haven't mentioned how this information is coming in. One line, are you trying to search and replace? using `preg_match`?

[Check this link out to see it working.](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/e9f)

Comment: This is a text file and i'd like to receive data from a user (name, e-mail, etc.).

Comment: It looks like a `yaml` file. Have you considered using [php's built-in yaml parsing?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file.php)